# find a string and replace a pattern before it - Notepad++

Tags: regex, string, replace, pattern-matching, notepad++

I am trying to acheive this using notepad++

Input file has pattern 
 
< a code snippet statement - this is variabe , followed by.. > ( Quality in parenthesis  )

```
-- "command xyz d 
   command rererere 
   command ;" ( fair quality)
---- "command xyz d 
   command rereredfdfdre 
   command ffdfdfdf ;" ( good quality)
---- "command xffddyz d 
   command rerfdferere 
   command ;" ( good quality)
----"command fdfdfxyz d 
   command refffdrerere 
   command fdfdff;" (    fair quality)
```

What I want to do is 
--Look for all instances where there is `( fair quality )` ( note that spacing between `( and fair` is variable and  then delete the entire statement with `( fair quality )`

 o/p is like this :

```
---- "command xyz d 
   command rereredfdfdre 
   command ffdfdfdf ;" ( good quality)
---- "command xffddyz d 
   command rerfdferere 
   command ;" ( good quality)
```

I tried some basic regex replace search for `( fair quality)`but how do I delete the entire string before it `from x to y` ?

Please dont assume the spacing pattern is regular. It will change 
e.g

```
"command    xyz..(   fair quality);"
"command  xyz (fair quality   );"
```

there isnt any regularity in the spacing  between 2 strings , which could be of use for regex work.

Also sometimes there are needless newlines in between e.g.

```
"command    
xyz..(   fair 
quality);"
```

So end of the line assumption also does not help
So the precise regex logic would be 
-- Go find me instances of `fair`
-- Find 1st instance of `command` before that instance of `fair` 
-- Find 1st instance of `"` before `command` . We will call this `X` 
-- Find 1st instance of `"` after `fair` . We will call this `Y`
-- Delete from `X` to `Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

- Find what: `-+\s*"[^"]+?"\s*\(\s*fair quality\)`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Repalce all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
-+              : one or more dash
\s*             : 0 or more spaces
"               : a double quote
[^"]+?          : one or more any character that is not a double quote
"               : a double quote
\s*             : 0 or more spaces
\(              : an open parenthesis
\s*             : 0 or more spaces
fair quality    : literally 'fair quality'
\)              : a close parenthesis
```

Answer (score 1):

you need regex with [temper greedy token solution](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)

find

```
-*\s*"command\b((?!\bquality\b\s*\)).)*\(\s*fair\s+quality\s*\)(;")?\r?\n?
```

replace with empty, make sure Regular expression and `.` matches newline is selected

regex details:

- `-*\s*"command\b` - matches 1st instance of " before command
- `((?!\bquality\b\s*\)).)*` - match any char that is not part of
  `quality)` with temper greedy token
- `\(\s*fair\s+quality\s*\)(;")?\r?\n?` - match the `fair quality` part,
  including `;"` and newline behind

input test

```
-- "command xyz d 
   command rererere 
   command ;" ( fair quality)
---- "command xyz d 
   command rereredfdfdre 
   command ffdfdfdf ;" ( good quality)
---- "command xffddyz d 
   command rerfdferere 
   command ;" ( good quality)
----"command fdfdfxyz d 
   command refffdrerere 
   command fdfdff;" (    fair quality)
  ----"command fdfdfxyz d 
   command refffdrerere 
command    
xyz..(   fair 
quality);"
"command    xyz..(   fair quality);"
"command  xyz (fair quality   );"
```

output

```
---- "command xyz d 
   command rereredfdfdre 
   command ffdfdfdf ;" ( good quality)
---- "command xffddyz d 
   command rerfdferere 
   command ;" ( good quality)
```